# Is the alpha channel supported in Minecraft tellraw?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I'm trying to add transparency to Minecraft tellraw so text can be partly transparent, and I'm stuck.  I've tried to add it via hex code, in the format `#AARRGGBB` and the alpha value is completely ignored.  I know it is supported in someway since I can use translucent images in unicode, I just don't know how to add it without using unicode.  Is there a way to add it in the color value?  Does Minecraft have a different value for alpha values?  Or is this not possible?  A solution without using unicode is what I need.

Comment: Usually it's `#RRGGBBAA`, have you tried that?

Comment: @Penguin yes I have.  It makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

you were right about the AARRGGBB order, however, the alpha channel is not supported in tellraw.